# Copy all files matching pattern from dir and subdirs into a single dir

Tags: r, copy

I have multiple folders into the path: "/home/user/IAT/main/assets/"

Each folder have the following structure: "~/assets **/lroot/images/batch0001/samples/**"

AllFolders

```
lroot
  images
    batch0001
       samples
          figure_12.png
          figure_17.png
          ...
  thumbnails
  dataframes

all_g2
  images
    batch0001
       samples
          figure_y32.png
          figure_x79.png
          ...
  thumbnails

  dataframes

before_g1
  images
    batch0001
       samples
          figure_2.jpg
          figure_17.jpg
          ...
  thumbnails
  dataframes
```

I have a *.txt with name of some images (without extension) into this folders.
for example: figure_12, figure_17, figure_x79, figure_2 and figure_17

I would to copy this images in folder `samples` referenced in *.txt to another folder in Desktop.

How could I to do that in R?

Thank's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently figured out how to do this.  Below I use the magick package to create a couple of test images.

```
library(magick)
image1 = image_blank(600,600,col="darkred")
image_write(image1, path="./tst1/image1.png")
image2 = image_blank(600,600,col="darkblue")
image_write(image2, path="./tst1/image2.png")

images=c("image1.png","image2.png")

pathOld = "./tst1/"
pathNew = "./tst1/tst2/"
for (i in 1:length(images)) {
  fileOld = paste0(pathOld,images[i])
  fileNew = paste0(pathNew,images[i])

  file.copy(fileOld,fileNew)
  print(c(fileOld,fileNew,i))
}
```